# How to bind keys from a specific keyboard

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, xmonad, xbindkeys

I would usually use xbindkeys to bind a key or key combination to a command in Ubuntu. I now have two separate keyboard inputs and I would like to bind keys from one of these keyboards to commands (but not on the other keyboard).

How do I go about this?

I use xmonad as my window manager if that makes any difference...

Comment: I doubt that's possible. You can bind commands to almost arbitrary key combinations, but not to a particular keyboard.