# Is it possible to have a complex macro layout using multiple keyboards?

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, ubuntu-mate

I am a video editor and I love to rely mostly on the keyboard. The software I use allows me to create loads of shortcuts for all the commands I like to use. However, for some of these commands, I might have to use a combination that includes <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SOME KEY</kbd>
, which slows down the process for me a little bit.

What I would like to do is get another keyboard, where I can use one as the main input keyboard, and use the other one as a macro keyboard where I can assign some of the keys to those complex shortcuts.

The macro keyboards I have managed to find all seem to rely on some software that doesn't have a Linux version (correct me if I am wrong).

So I wanted to see if there is a way where I can replicate the functionality of those macro keyboards on Linux. I will try clarifying in detail what I would like to do.

1. I have two keyboards.
2. First one used regularly as an input device for typing or any normal input.
3. Second one is used to simulate specific key strokes and combinations.
4. This way, if I click the <kbd>S</kbd> key for instance on the first keyboard, it sends an `s` keystroke, but if I press it on the second keyboard, it sends what key combination I have defined, let's say <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>, for instance.

I have looked online and some posts suggested `AutoKey` or `xdotool`. Aside from the fact that I couldn't get any of them to work properly, I also don't see a way to define which specific keyboard I would like to use.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 MATE.

Comment: A comment in this post https://askubuntu.com/questions/555218/how-to-bind-keys-from-a-specific-keybaord?rq=1 suggests it is not as such possible.

Comment: It actually appears to be possible. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35649/second-keyboard-to-run-commands

Comment: Unfortunatelly, actkbd does not appear in active development anymore. Installation on Ubuntu may not be easy.

Comment: I have actually compiled it form source, followed the tutorial, and managed to get it to work.. what I am trying to figure out now is how to send actual keystrokes.. I will try `xdotool`

Comment: Yep.. using it with `xdotool` seems to do the job.. I would like to explore other options though, to see if I can find something better