# Can I launch marcos and shortcuts from a second keyboard

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

I have a small numpad keyboard which I would like to use for launching marcos and shortcuts, alongside my regular keyboard. I can attach marcos and shortcuts to these keys (*i.e, numpad 1 minimises the active window*), but my primary keyboard numpad also activates the shortcut.

I would like a way to have the secondary keyboard act completely separately and to then attach shortcuts to it.

Here is the output I get from `xinput`.

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ LVT Recon gaming mouse                    id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ LVT Recon gaming mouse                    id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Corsair Corsair K30A Gaming Keyboard      id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SIGMACHIP USB Keyboard                    id=18   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Corsair Corsair K30A Gaming Keyboard      id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Corsair Corsair K30A Gaming Keyboard      id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ LVT Recon gaming mouse                    id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Corsair Corsair K30A Gaming Keyboard      id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ SIGMACHIP USB Keyboard                    id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ SIGMACHIP USB Keyboard                    id=19   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: Same question asked here, https://askubuntu.com/questions/1113803/is-it-possible-to-have-a-complex-macro-layout-using-multiple-keyboards?rq=1, unfortunatelly without answer.